# Tikz diagram next to bulleted list

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a number of diagrams that correspond to bulleted lists and I'd like them to be side by side in my thesis (there's enough space). How do I do this?

One of my bulleted lists:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{W}: $\{$\textit{w}$_1$, \textit{w}$_2$, \textit{w}$_3\}$
\item \textbf{R}: \textit{w}$_1$R\textit{w}$_2$, \textit{w}$_2$R\textit{w}$_1$, \textit{w}$_3$R\textit{w}$_1$
\item \textbf{S}: \textit{w}$_1$S\textit{w}$_3$
\item \textbf{\textit{v}}: \textit{v}$_{w1}$(A) = 1\\
\textit{v}$_{w2}$(A) = 1\\
\textit{v}$_{w3}$(A) = 0\\
\end{itemize}
```

And the corresponding diagram:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node
  distance=2.8cm, semithick]

  \node[state, label=below:{$A=1$}] (A) {$w_1$};
  \node[state, label=above:{$A=1$}] (B) [above left of=A] {$w_2$};
  \node[state, label=above:{$A=0$}] (C) [above right of=A] {$w_3$};

  \path[black] (A)
  edge [blue] node {} (B)
  edge [bend right, red] node {} (C)
  (B) edge [blue] node {} (A)
  (C) edge [blue] node {} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\noindent%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{W}: $\{$\textit{w}$_1$, \textit{w}$_2$, \textit{w}$_3\}$
\item \textbf{R}: \textit{w}$_1$R\textit{w}$_2$, \textit{w}$_2$R\textit{w}$_1$, \textit{w}$_3$R\textit{w}$_1$
\item \textbf{S}: \textit{w}$_1$S\textit{w}$_3$
\item \textbf{\textit{v}}: \textit{v}$_{w1}$(A) = 1\\
\textit{v}$_{w2}$(A) = 1\\
\textit{v}$_{w3}$(A) = 0\\
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node
  distance=2.8cm, semithick]

  \node[state, label=below:{$A=1$}] (A) {$w_1$};
  \node[state, label=above:{$A=1$}] (B) [above left of=A] {$w_2$};
  \node[state, label=above:{$A=0$}] (C) [above right of=A] {$w_3$};

  \path[black] (A)
  edge [blue] node {} (B)
  edge [bend right, red] node {} (C)
  (B) edge [blue] node {} (A)
  (C) edge [blue] node {} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
```